# Setting IF statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am setting up block rules on Stripe. I only want to accept debit cards beginning with the following number (494159,494160,435880) also known as Card BIN. I want to block payment if not equal to any of those numbers.

Block if card_bin != '494159' or '494160' or '435880'

I tried code above but it did not work. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1PMR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the image informs you that the `or` cannot be used with strings. You then also need to use `and` because you negate all.

Try:

```
card_bin != '494159' and card_bin != '494160' and card_bin != '435880'
```